# Require js, must reference the required object two times

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I define a script with no dependencies with require:

```
    define([], function () {
        var obj = {
             doSomething: function() {}
        }

        return : {
           obj : obj    
        }
    });
```

However when I have to use doSomething like this:

```
 require(['obj'], function (obj) {
            obj.obj.doSomething();
        });
```

What am I doing wrong, so I can't just use

```
obj.doSomething();
```

Comment: Also you dont need the empty array, if your module has no dependencies just directly pass the function to `define()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
  define([], function () {
        var obj = {
             doSomething: function() {}
        }

        return obj; 

    });
```